# Electron - Call function from view

Tags: electron, atom-editor

Hello I am new in electron and I am facing a problem, I want to execute a command on click button for that I am using a child_process of node. I have written a code for app.on('ready') and its working fine. But I need it on click below is my code please help..

```
function runExec() {
 child_process.exec('pwd', function(error, stdout, stderr){
  if(!error){
   console.log(stdout);
   setTimeout(function(){
    child_process.exec('ls -la', function(error, stdout, stderr){
      console.log(stdout);
    });
    }, 3000);
   }
 });
}
```

I want to run this function on click with jquery/index.html
HTML code is here:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 controls">
  <a id="btn-login" href="#" class="btn btn-success btnLogin">Login </a>
</div>
```

As I am hitting an API on click of login button and get response & I want to call that function too on same click or true response..

Any Idea..

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5):

So, it works in your main process but you want to trigger it when someone clicks on a button in your renderer process?

What you'll need to do is export the functionality in your main process and then use Electron's `remote` module to pull it into your renderer process.

In your main process, add the following code:

```
exports.runExec = runExec;
```

This will export your `runExec` function as `runExec` on the `remote` object when you import it.

Now, in your renderer code (I am assuming your main file is called `main.js`, but it might be named something else, which is totally okay, just replace `./main` with whatever the name of your file is on the second line):

```
var electron = require('electron');
var runExec = electron.remote.require('./main').runExec;

var loginButton = document.querySelector('. btnLogin');

loginButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  runExec();
});
```

Electron's `remote` module acts as a proxy to the main process. So when someone clicks on the "Login" button, your renderer process will trigger the `runExec` function from the main process.

Comment: Yeah this function is working fine if I call it in app.on('ready') event

Comment: Steve I have added "exports.runExec = runExec;" line in main.js and rest the code is pasted in html file but its throwing me an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" and function is also not working :(

Comment: I have done it :) thanks for your help I did it with the help of "ipc"